# Write a Java Program to connect to HornetQ Messaging Service in Jboss EAP 6.3?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq

I am using Jboss EAP 6.3 and need to use Messaging facility. 
I have worked in Jboss 4x, where we can make connection easily using following code:

```
public static final String PROVIDER_URL = "jnp://localhost:5445";
   public static final String JNP_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces";
   public static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";

   private static Context initialContext;

   public static Context getInitialContextForClient() throws NamingException{
          if(initialContext == null){
                 Properties prop = new Properties();
                 prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
                 prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,JNP_INTERFACES);
                 prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
                 initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);
          }
          return initialContext;
   }
```

Will above way work in EAP 6.3 to connect to HornetQ? If yes, what other configurations are required? Also, i found 1099 is also not configured by default in standalone.xml.

Following are by default settings done for HornetQ in Standalone-full.xml file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                    <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                </jms-queue>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Following are socket bindings in same file:

```
<socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
```

I tried it like below because unable to see org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory class in Jboss EAP 6.3:

```
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"localhost:5445"); 
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory");
prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
```

Currently, it is throwing Connection Exception.

Could anyone please suggest or submit a java program on how to achieve connection with Hornetq in Jboss EAP 6.3?

**Update**:
I still do not know whether i am following correct procedure of doing the same.

Following is exceptions which i am getting:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module
```

I have checked its jboss-client.jar in bin/client and found the above interface is not present there but is present in previous versions which contains jbiss-allclient.jar. I do not think putting that in this jboss version is correct to do.

Comment: It could be helpful if you add a full stacktrace.

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner

I have updated exceptions above. It will be better if i can get information on which strategy should i follow in above two snippets and which one is correct or should i not follow any of above?

Comment: Take care, i think you try to use the port 5445 for the message queue and your Initialcontext-configuration. Both of them can't work on the same port. I think you are using the wrong port for your initialContext.

Comment: I have tried above snippet one by one but it is not working for me. For 1099 it is connect exeption which is of course because JBoss EAP 6.3 does not have any configuration on 1099. So 5445 should be used but Those JNP, NamingContextFactory Classes does not work on it. I am using hit and trials from various ways. Lets see which works.

Comment: Does it work if you create your initialContext without properties -> initialContext = new InitialContext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click [this jboss](http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/helloworld-jms/) link; which contains quickstart program which resolves mentioned problem.

1) Download the code; Import pom.xml of run jboss-helloworld-jms in netbeans. Run clean build.

2) Use this link to resolve maven build problems:
[Pom not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909664/failed-to-execute-goal-on-project-unable-to-find-pom-in-project/30909768#30909768)

3) Following is snippet which used to connect to server

```
private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/queue/test";
private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "quickstartUser";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "quickstartPwd1!";
private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "remote://localhost:4447";

String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
log.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\"");
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
log.info("Found connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\" in JNDI");
```

4) Create User "quickstartUser"/"quickstartPwd1!", in Jboss EAP 6.3; using adduser.bat in application realm

5) Do check whether these jms/queue/test and jms/RemoteConnectionFactory exist in Standalone.xml.

6) Run code as simple Java Application and magic is there.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace i assume you didn't adept your old JNDI settings to JBoss EAP 6.3

From: http://blog.akquinet.de/2014/09/26/jboss-eap-wildfly-three-ways-to-invoke-remote-ejbs/

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

prop.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", false);
prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

Context context = new InitialContext(prop);
```

Your application cant instantiate the initialContext, which is a problem you should focus on.

Also, it looks kinda weird to me that both, the message queue and your jndi is trying to connect localhost:5445.

Comment: It says : ConnectionFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ConnectionFactory

Comment: Please add full stacktraces, that would be really helpful. Also, often there is more information in the logs than the last exception message, plus, the failure causing code would be good.