# Failed to execute goal on project. Unable to find POM in project

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am trying to build an application having following dependency.

```
<properties>
    <version.jboss.as>7.5.0.Final-redhat-21</version.jboss.as>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.as}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is an example which i found on Red Hat Site - http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/helloworld-jms/

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2.(also tried it using Maven command in dos and eclipse) I am getting an error while building and following is log of same:

```
Building JBoss EAP Quickstart: helloworld-jms 6.4.0.GA
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jms-client-bom/7.5.0.Final-redhat-21/jboss-as-jms-client-bom-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.pom

The POM for org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jms-client-bom:pom:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21 is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.268s
Finished at: Thu Jun 18 13:27:43 IST 2015
Final Memory: 6M/121M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project jboss-helloworld-jms: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jboss.quickstarts.eap:jboss-helloworld-jms:jar:6.4.0.GA: Failure to find org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jms-client-bom:pom:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I can locate file on following path:

https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jms-client-bom/7.5.0.Final-redhat-21/jboss-as-jms-client-bom-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add *redhat repo* in your `pom.xml` or `setting.xml`. [Install and Use the Maven Repository](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Grid/6/html/Getting_Started_Guide/chap-Install_and_Use_the_Maven_Repository.html)

such as:

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-techpreview-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Enterprise Technology Preview  Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```